# Problem in using $Component notation

Tags: visualforce, css, html

On my visualforce page there is an input text field and two buttons.I am trying to hit the second button on my page with the 'enter' key by calling a javascript on text field, where in my target is on my seccond button. I am trying to access the button id using $Component notation, however everytime its value is null. 
Tried using the nested ids but didn't work.

Any useful links or suggestions are appreciated.

Below is my visualforce page[image]

Comment: Nazi, know that you can copy/past code and use the {} button in the editor to format it as a code block. That's more readable than an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $Component notation is quite picky about the correct number of prefixes etc.  I used to build this up in baby steps and check the page source each time to see if the $Component renders anything or is blank.

These days I use a JQuery selector to find the element that ends with the particular id - that way I don't have to worry about the prefixes.

I include JQuery from a CDN, but you could load it as a static resource :

```
<apex:includescript 
      value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" />
```

and then use an ends with selector as follows:

```
if (keyCode==13)
{
   $('[id$=Auth_id]').click();
}
```

The key aspect of the selector is the `[id$=Auth_id]` this translates to 'the element with an id that ends with Auth_id'. I've also used the JQuery click method to chain the button click.